# How to understand this MySQL query containing a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please help me understand the below query, I am fairly new to SQL.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM   tblservicesubroutes ts 
     INNER JOIN tblservicelegs sl ON sl.serviceid = ts.serviceid 
     AND sl.fromcityid = ts.fromcityid AND sl.tocityid = ts.tocityid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query finds the **number of rows** in the resultant table obtained after joining two tables `tblservicesubroutes` and `tblservicelegs` based on three columns common to both tables, which are `serviceid,fromcityid,tocityid`

In simple terms it finds the number of rows from both tables where there is a match between the columns specified after **ON**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here are you trying to say that after joining table tblservicesubroutes and tblservicelegs, it is just counting those rows where   serviceid,fromcityid,tocityid coulns are same? Like in MS excel it just checking true and false and just returning the count where these three are true?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-inner-joins.htm Checkout this example. Here the difference is that 3 columns are used for join operation. Also, the example shows the content of resultant table where as your query gives the number of rows in the resultant table

Comment: Thank you so much. The link is really helpful.